# SQL Error 00905. 00000 - "missing keyword"

Tags: oracle, plsql, keyword

I am trying to execute this query ;

```
Grant SELECT on TYPE PPZ_C.BTS_BAUTEIL_STATION_INFO to PPZ_W;
```

and I get the folowing error:

> Error starting at line : 3 in command - Grant SELECT on TYPE
>   PPZ_C.BTS_BAUTEIL_STATION_INFO to PPZ_W Error report - ORA-00905:
>   missing keyword
>   00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Does anyone know what keyword I am missing ?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you need to remove `TYPE`. This will fix your first part of issue.
Try this
`Grant SELECT on PPZ_C.BTS_BAUTEIL_STATION_INFO to PPZ_W`

Now when you execute the above , you will further get the error:

> ORA-02305: only EXECUTE, DEBUG, and UNDER privileges are valid for
>   types

Which means you cannot grant `select` on any `type`.   Only EXECUTE, DEBUG, and UNDER privileges are valid for types.

So you can use `EXECUTE` when you want it to be used in select statement  :

```
Grant EXECUTE on PPZ_C.BTS_BAUTEIL_STATION_INFO to PPZ_W;
```

EDIT:
Your select statement should be :

```
SELECT ppz_bts.na_stat_anf( PPZ_C.BTS_BAUTEIL_STATION_INFO ('','IG','12345679') ) FROM dual;
```

See demo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE myschema.array_t is varray(2) of number ; 

---Running in My schema
SQL> select * from table(array_t('1','2'));

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           1
           2

--Granted from myschema to otherschema
SQL> grant execute on  myschema.array_t to othersschema ;

--Running in otherschema

SQL> select * from table(myschema.array_t('1','2'));

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           1
           2
```

Comment: I what that the user PPZ_W to be able to make this select :

Comment: SELECT ppz_bts.na_stat_anf( bts_bauteil_station_info('','IG','12345679') ) FROM dual;

Comment: Which of EXECUTE, DEBUG, and UNDER should I use ?

Comment: SELECT ppz_bts.na_stat_anf( bts_bauteil_station_info('','IG','12345679') ) FROM dual;

Comment: I guess you are not follwoing what has been answered. You are still missing the schemaname.. Use this .`SELECT ppz_bts.na_stat_anf( PPZ_C.BTS_BAUTEIL_STATION_INFO ('','IG','12345679') ) 
FROM dual;`

Answer (score 2):

When Oracle receives requests for type information, it verifies that the requestor has EXECUTE privilege on the type before supplying the requested information.
Try this :

```
Grant EXECUTE on PPZ_C.BTS_BAUTEIL_STATION_INFO to PPZ_W;
```

Then try doing :

```
SELECT ppz_bts.na_stat_anf( PPZ_C.bts_bauteil_station_info('','IG','12345679') ) 
FROM dual;
```

Comment: SELECT ppz_bts.na_stat_anf( bts_bauteil_station_info('','IG','12345679') ) FROM dual;

Comment: I get this error ORA-00904: "BTS_BAUTEIL_STATION_INFO": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 29

Comment: looks like PPZ_W still does not have perrmision to that type

Comment: That's because you didn't specify the schema the type belongs to when you referenced it in the select statement (although you did when you wrote the grant statement). You should be referring to it as `ppz_c.bts_bauteil_station_info` if you're calling it from a different schema.